# APT isn't installing man pages by default

Tags: debian, apt, man

I have installed a minimal Debian 9 through CD image. I configured Apt to not install recommended packages and now the system don't have any man page.

`man apt-get`, `man mkdir`, or `man ping` doesn't show any man page; instead, I get

```
bash: man: command not found
```

Comment: "man pages" are on-line : `man apt-get` https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get **or** http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html ... `man mkdir` (1) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html , etc. etc.

Comment: @Knud since the OP is using Debian, the appropriate site for online manpages is [`manpages.debian.org`](https://manpages.debian.org).

Answer (score 15):

```
bash: man: command not found
```

means that you need to install [the `man-db` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/man-db).

Manpages are installed by default in most cases, because [Debian policy strongly encourages them to be shipped in the same package as the commands themselves](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#manual-pages):

> Each program, utility, and function should have an associated manual page included in the same package.

Comment: Sure, but there is any reason why Debian 9 doesn't ship with `man-db` (and hence `man`) installed by default?

Comment: @Pablo what makes you think it doesn’t? The OP explicitly performed a minimal install and configured `apt` to ignore “Recommends”. That’s not the default installation. `man-db` is “Priority: standard” and installed in the default installation, but not in the minimal one.

Comment: OK, so [Digital Ocean Debian default droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/linux-distribution/debian/) (at least with 9.6 x64) installation is a minimal one.

Answer (score 2):

The `apt` package which contain `apt-get`, also contains the manpage for `apt-get` (it even contains it in 7 languages), so if you have `apt-get` installed, you really should have the manpage. If you don't you've messed up your system in a way beyond what any packaging system can help you with.

Similar can be said for `mkdir` in the `coreutils` package, and for `ping` in `iputils-ping`.

But configuring APT to not install recommends (which I also always do, and believe to be a good thing), will mean that you don't get manpages of any program where the Debian developer making the package has chosen not to include it in the package, but in a package that is only a recommandation. I guess there's a lot of options, but some number of programs have manpages in the `manpages` package.

Comment: Manpages are supposed to be shipped in the package alongside the command they document. The `manpages` package does document some commands, but [only a small number](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/manpages/filelist). Other packages which don’t include manpages tend to do so for licensing reasons (*e.g.* `gcc`).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW if you try and install Debian under Windows using WSL, then you do not get the man pages as default (I imagine this may also be a minimal installation). This is easily remedied using the method that Stephen Kitt suggests in a previous answer, but for the avoidance of doubt the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install man-db
```

If you install the build-essential packages (e.g. to install a C compiler), then you MAY need to also use:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
```